# Как получить значения в многомерном массиве объектов

Tags: javascript, json

Имеется массив объектов, как получить значения вида: arr.push(name + 24hour lowest price)?

Пример массива:

```
{
success: true,
currency: "USD",
timestamp: 1598651972
items_list: {

  3rd Commando Company | KSK: {
    name: "3rd Commando Company | KSK",
    price: {
      24_hours: {
        average: 2.76,
        median: 2.81,
        sold: "517",
        standard_deviation: "3.45",
        lowest_price: 2.55,
        highest_price: 2.89
        },
      7_days: {
        average: 2.79,
        median: 2.79,
        sold: "3095",
        standard_deviation: "2.99",
        lowest_price: 2.55,
        highest_price: 2.92
        },
      30_days: {
        average: 2.84,
        median: 2.86,
        sold: "13238",
        standard_deviation: "3.77",
        lowest_price: 2.55,
        highest_price: 3.06
        },
      all_time: {
        average: 3.84,
        median: 2.84,
        sold: "256893",
        standard_deviation: "30.03",
        lowest_price: 2.01,
        highest_price: 12.78
       }
     },
first_sale_date: "1574118000"
},

  AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred): {
    name: "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
    price: {
      24_hours: {
        average: 17.09,
        median: 17.19,
        sold: "42",
        standard_deviation: "5.57",
        lowest_price: 14.76,
        highest_price: 18.5
        },
      7_days: {
        average: 17.74,
        median: 17.68,
        sold: "293",
        standard_deviation: "4.7",
        lowest_price: 14.26,
        highest_price: 19.33
        },
      30_days: {
        average: 18.44,
        median: 18.39,
        sold: "1124",
        standard_deviation: "5.49",
        lowest_price: 14.26,
        highest_price: 20.71
        },
      all_time: {
        average: 12.69,
        median: 14.82,
        sold: "165598",
        standard_deviation: "31.33",
        lowest_price: 6.83,
        highest_price: 33.7
        }
      },
first_sale_date: "1432764000"
}
```

Comment: О, чё по скинам?) Недавно как раз возился с другим сайтом в получении api. Тебе нужен рекурсивный перебор, потому что вложений может быть сколько угодно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш json не валидный.

Если это строка, то ключи объектов не могут начинаться с числа (`24_hours`), в противном случае это должна быть строка, заключённая в кавычки (`"24_hours"`).

```js
var json = {
  "success": true,
  "currency": "USD",
  "timestamp": 1598651972,
  "items_list": {
    "3rdCommandoCompany|KSK": {
      "name": "3rd Commando Company | KSK",
      "price": {
        "24_hours": {
          "average": 2.76,
          "median": 2.81,
          "sold": 517,
          "standard_deviation": 3.45,
          "lowest_price": 2.55,
          "highest_price": 2.89
        },
        "7_days": {
          "average": 2.79,
          "median": 2.79,
          "sold": 3095,
          "standard_deviation": 2.99,
          "lowest_price": 2.55,
          "highest_price": 2.92
        },
        "30_days": {
          "average": 2.84,
          "median": 2.86,
          "sold": 13238,
          "standard_deviation": 3.77,
          "lowest_price": 2.55,
          "highest_price": 3.06
        },
        "all_time": {
          "average": 3.84,
          "median": 2.84,
          "sold": 256893,
          "standard_deviation": 30.03,
          "lowest_price": 2.01,
          "highest_price": 12.78
        }
      },
      "first_sale_date": 1574118000
    },
    "AK-47|AquamarineRevenge(Battle-Scarred)": {
      "name": "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
      "price": {
        "24_hours": {
          "average": 17.09,
          "median": 17.19,
          "sold": "42",
          "standard_deviation": "5.57",
          "lowest_price": 14.76,
          "highest_price": 18.5
        },
        "7_days": {
          "average": 17.74,
          "median": 17.68,
          "sold": 293,
          "standard_deviation": 4.7,
          "lowest_price": 14.26,
          "highest_price": 19.33
        },
        "30_days": {
          "average": 18.44,
          "median": 18.39,
          "sold": 1124,
          "standard_deviation": 5.49,
          "lowest_price": 14.26,
          "highest_price": 20.71
        },
        "all_time": {
          "average": 12.69,
          "median": 14.82,
          "sold": 165598,
          "standard_deviation": 31.33,
          "lowest_price": 6.83,
          "highest_price": 33.7
        }
      },
      "first_sale_date": 1432764000
    }
  }
};



let lowest = Object.entries(json.items_list)
.map(list => list[1])
.map(item => item.price['24_hours'].lowest_price);

console.log(lowest);
```

```
// получаем из объекта ассоциативный массив
let lowest = Object.entries(json.items_list)

/* Выбираем всё после 0, так как 0 это строка и название,  
которое мы не можем знать заранее */
.map(list => list[1])

/* Выбираем все price. Если ключ это строка в нашем случае, то берём в 
кавычки и квадратные скобки */
.map(item => item.price['24_hours'].lowest_price);
```

Можно и по-другому.

```
let lowest = Object.entries(json.items_list)
.map(item => [item[0], item[1].price['24_hours'].lowest_price]);

// lowest будет содержать массив из name и lowest_price
```

Comment: `Object.entries(json.items_list).map(list => list[1])` → `Object.values(json.items_list)`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME А разве `Object.values` не отсеит ключи, которые нам так нужны?

Comment: О_о отсеит. Но в коде из ответа-примера не было вывода тех ключей...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Верно, но всё равно придётся использовать `24_hours` в квадратных скобках 

Answer (score 2):

Нужно всего-то два вложенных цикла [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
let data = getData();

let items = data.items_list
let arr = [];

for (let key in items) {
  let name = items[key].name;
  let price_obj = items[key].price;
  
  for (let interval in price_obj) {
    let lowest = price_obj[interval].lowest_price;
    arr.push( name + " && " + interval + " && " + lowest );
  }
}

console.log(arr);

/***/
function getData() {
  return {
    success: true,
    currency: "USD",
    timestamp: 1598651972,
    items_list: {

      "3 rd Commando Company | KSK": {
        name: "3rd Commando Company | KSK",
        price: {
          "24 _hours": {
            average: 2.76,
            median: 2.81,
            sold: "517",
            standard_deviation: "3.45",
            lowest_price: 2.55,
            highest_price: 2.89
          },
          "7 _days": {
            average: 2.79,
            median: 2.79,
            sold: "3095",
            standard_deviation: "2.99",
            lowest_price: 2.55,
            highest_price: 2.92
          },
          "30 _days": {
            average: 2.84,
            median: 2.86,
            sold: "13238",
            standard_deviation: "3.77",
            lowest_price: 2.55,
            highest_price: 3.06
          },
          all_time: {
            average: 3.84,
            median: 2.84,
            sold: "256893",
            standard_deviation: "30.03",
            lowest_price: 2.01,
            highest_price: 12.78
          }
        },
        first_sale_date: "1574118000"
      },

      "AK - 47 | Aquamarine Revenge(Battle - Scarred)": {
        name: "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
        price: {
          "24 _hours": {
            average: 17.09,
            median: 17.19,
            sold: "42",
            standard_deviation: "5.57",
            lowest_price: 14.76,
            highest_price: 18.5
          },
          "7 _days": {
            average: 17.74,
            median: 17.68,
            sold: "293",
            standard_deviation: "4.7",
            lowest_price: 14.26,
            highest_price: 19.33
          },
          "30 _days": {
            average: 18.44,
            median: 18.39,
            sold: "1124",
            standard_deviation: "5.49",
            lowest_price: 14.26,
            highest_price: 20.71
          },
          "all_time": {
            average: 12.69,
            median: 14.82,
            sold: "165598",
            standard_deviation: "31.33",
            lowest_price: 6.83,
            highest_price: 33.7
          }
        },
        first_sale_date: "1432764000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Или по-другому, через ([for ... of](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)):

```js
let data = getData();

let arr = [];

for ( let item of Object.values(data.items_list) ) {
  let name = item.name;
  let prices = item.price;
  
  for ( let [interval, price_obj] of Object.entries(prices) ) {
    let lowest = price_obj.lowest_price;
    arr.push( name + " && " + interval + " && " + lowest );
  }
}

console.log(arr);

// *google → Object.values, Object.entries, Деструктурирующее присваивание

/***/
function getData() {
  return {
    success: true,
    currency: "USD",
    timestamp: 1598651972,
    items_list: {

      "3 rd Commando Company | KSK": {
        name: "3rd Commando Company | KSK",
        price: {
          "24 _hours": {
            average: 2.76,
            median: 2.81,
            sold: "517",
            standard_deviation: "3.45",
            lowest_price: 2.55,
            highest_price: 2.89
          },
          "7 _days": {
            average: 2.79,
            median: 2.79,
            sold: "3095",
            standard_deviation: "2.99",
            lowest_price: 2.55,
            highest_price: 2.92
          },
          "30 _days": {
            average: 2.84,
            median: 2.86,
            sold: "13238",
            standard_deviation: "3.77",
            lowest_price: 2.55,
            highest_price: 3.06
          },
          all_time: {
            average: 3.84,
            median: 2.84,
            sold: "256893",
            standard_deviation: "30.03",
            lowest_price: 2.01,
            highest_price: 12.78
          }
        },
        first_sale_date: "1574118000"
      },

      "AK - 47 | Aquamarine Revenge(Battle - Scarred)": {
        name: "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
        price: {
          "24 _hours": {
            average: 17.09,
            median: 17.19,
            sold: "42",
            standard_deviation: "5.57",
            lowest_price: 14.76,
            highest_price: 18.5
          },
          "7 _days": {
            average: 17.74,
            median: 17.68,
            sold: "293",
            standard_deviation: "4.7",
            lowest_price: 14.26,
            highest_price: 19.33
          },
          "30 _days": {
            average: 18.44,
            median: 18.39,
            sold: "1124",
            standard_deviation: "5.49",
            lowest_price: 14.26,
            highest_price: 20.71
          },
          "all_time": {
            average: 12.69,
            median: 14.82,
            sold: "165598",
            standard_deviation: "31.33",
            lowest_price: 6.83,
            highest_price: 33.7
          }
        },
        first_sale_date: "1432764000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

P.s. Можно еще написать через регулярные выражения, и делать вид, что вы хаЦкер:

```js
let x = data().match(/name:\s?.*?,\s*price:\s*\{(\s*.*?\{(?:.|\s)*?\},?)+/g)
  .map((e,i) => (i = e.replace(/(name:\s?.*?,\s*price:\s*\{)/g, ""), 
  i.match(/\s*(.*?):\s*\{/g)
  .map((v,i) => e.match(/(?<=name:\s?)"([^"]+)/)[1] + " && " +
  v.match(/\s*(.*?):\s*\{/)[1] + " && " +
  e.match(/(?<=lowest_price:\s+)\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g)[i]) )).flat();
  
console.log(x);

function data() {
  return `{
success: true,
currency: "USD",
timestamp: 1598651972
items_list: {

  3rd Commando Company | KSK: {
    name: "3rd Commando Company | KSK",
    price: {
      24_hours: {
        average: 2.76,
        median: 2.81,
        sold: "517",
        standard_deviation: "3.45",
        lowest_price: 2.55,
        highest_price: 2.89
        },
      7_days: {
        average: 2.79,
        median: 2.79,
        sold: "3095",
        standard_deviation: "2.99",
        lowest_price: 2.55,
        highest_price: 2.92
        },
      30_days: {
        average: 2.84,
        median: 2.86,
        sold: "13238",
        standard_deviation: "3.77",
        lowest_price: 2.55,
        highest_price: 3.06
        },
      all_time: {
        average: 3.84,
        median: 2.84,
        sold: "256893",
        standard_deviation: "30.03",
        lowest_price: 2.01,
        highest_price: 12.78
       }
     },
first_sale_date: "1574118000"
},

  AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred): {
    name: "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)",
    price: {
      24_hours: {
        average: 17.09,
        median: 17.19,
        sold: "42",
        standard_deviation: "5.57",
        lowest_price: 14.76,
        highest_price: 18.5
        },
      7_days: {
        average: 17.74,
        median: 17.68,
        sold: "293",
        standard_deviation: "4.7",
        lowest_price: 14.26,
        highest_price: 19.33
        },
      30_days: {
        average: 18.44,
        median: 18.39,
        sold: "1124",
        standard_deviation: "5.49",
        lowest_price: 14.26,
        highest_price: 20.71
        },
      all_time: {
        average: 12.69,
        median: 14.82,
        sold: "165598",
        standard_deviation: "31.33",
        lowest_price: 6.83,
        highest_price: 33.7
        }
      },
first_sale_date: "1432764000"
  }`;
}
```

Увы, такое невозмжно понять, можно только написать!)
Если всё же захочется какие-то куски разобрать, ссылаюсь на → https://regex101.com/

Comment: Ну какие могут быть регулярки и двойные циклы в перечислении объекта?) Это костыли и велосипеды. На нативном ES6 доступны все для удобства инструменты. `array.filter`, `array.map` или `array. forEach`...

Comment: @Doofу `console.log( Object.values(data.items_list).map( e => Object.entries(e.price).map(([interval, obj]) => `${e.name} && ${interval} && ${obj.lowest_price}`) ).flat() );` — Экмаскриптее некуда. Насчитал 5 циклов. Может лучше 2, и в более понятном виде?) А регулярка написана по приколу...